# About the characters of representations of groups

Tags: representation-theory

I want to ask a question about the characters of representations of groups.

we all know that the equivalent representations have the same character, and the character is a class function, so what about the non-equivalent representations? are their characters different?! How?!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true. If $G$ is a (finite) group and $\pi$ and $\rho$ are two representations of $G$. Then $\pi$ and $\rho$ are isomorphic (equivalent) if and only if the character of $\pi$ is equal to the character of $\rho$.

Comment: Well! dose it mean that the two characters are different for any member of the group G?
Are the direct images of G by the different characters distinct or not?

Comment: @sososos: No, that characters are different doesn't mean that they are different at all elements of the group.

Comment: OK. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume we're dealing with finite groups and complex representations. Since trace is invariant under conjugation, equivalent representations have the same character. In the opposite direction, every representation is the direct sum of irreducible representations, and any distinct irreducible representations have orthogonal characters by Schur's lemma. It follows that distinct (not necessarily irreducible) representations have distinct characters.